# Updating a MySQL column using values from other columns from the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I just created a new `GEOMETRY` column `p` and need to populate values for all existing rows in the table for `p` based on existing values in cols `lat` and `lng`.

**Problem:** Updating a single column using the query below works well because I typed in the `lat` and `lng` values manually. But when I want MySQL to update col `p` for all rows in the tables, the query that I used does not set any values to col `p`. I think it has to do with the sub-query (?), but I am not sure how to make it work properly. Thanks!

**Query that works**

```
UPDATE listings 
SET p = GeomFromText('POINT(39.948177 -75.174324)') 
WHERE listing_id = '585221';
```

**Query that sets no value**

*Added a `WHERE` clause so I dont destroy the entire table when testing. I actually want to do the `UPDATE` query for ALL rows in the table*

```
UPDATE listings 
SET p = GeomFromText('POINT(lat lng)') 
WHERE listing_id = '585221';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and what about this (remove the geomfromtext function)

UPDATE listings 
SET p = POINT(lat, lng)
WHERE listing_id = '585221';

or you can go like this

UPDATE listings SET p = GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',lat,' ',lng,')'));

Comment: If i use `SET p = POINT(lat, lng)` which works, should I change the column type from `GEOMETRY` to `POINT`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate your values to form a proper argument for `GeomFromText`:

```
UPDATE listings 
SET p = GeomFromText('POINT(' || lat || ' ' || lng || ')') 
WHERE listing_id = '585221';
```

The pipe operator (`||`) is used to concatenate strings. But a better solution is to use the `Point` function directly:

```
UPDATE listings 
SET p = Point(lat, lng) 
WHERE listing_id = '585221';
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQLite / Spatialite it's

```
UPDATE mytable SET location = GeomFromText('POINT('||latitude||" "||longitude||')');
```